# Flexbox children shrink up to a certain point (but don't expand if they don't need to)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm a having a bit of an issue here. I have a flexbox container with children of different sizes. Based on quantity and their content children might overflow the parent.

[image: A container with 5 children (overflowing)]

What I want is the children to shrink so they *try to fit* in the parent container. I did that by adding shrink and overflow properties to the children. So far so good.

```
.container > div {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

I end up with something like this:

[image: A container with 5 shrunk children]

Now I want them to shrink **but up to a certain point** (lets say 80px). I don't care if they end up overflowing the container but I don't want to render any smaller than 80px.

Of course, I added `min-width: 80px` to the children... but here is my problem.  I want the children to shrink up to 80px but I don't want any of those that were smaller than 80px already (like Child1, Child4 and Child5) I don't want them to be enlarged by the min-width property (or, I want them to shrink further up to `min-content`)

In other words. I don't want this:

[image: Container with shrunk children (and enlarged ones!)]

I would love to have something like this:

[image]

I tried doing something like `min-width: min(min-content, 80px)` but of course, didn't work.

Here is an small codepen with the issue: https://codepen.io/claudiofpen/pen/QWELVJO

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container > div {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-width: min-content;
}
.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* I don't want the following css classes, I cannot 
 tell in before hand which children are going to have 
 a larger content */
.container > div:nth-child(2), 
.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  min-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Longer Child 2</div>
  <div>Longer Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
  <div>Child 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it need to be flex? Could you not just use a max-width: https://jsfiddle.net/h3setkjg/1/

Comment: @Pete no it doesn't, I could use any given display.  However `max-width` won't work.  If there is a single item and there is enough space for it I don't want it to be restricted to that max width.

Comment: I think then, the only way would be js - I don't believe there is a way to have a max width only if the width of the children is longer than the parent and the width of the child is longer than a certain width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)'s solution solves the problem of ensuring that a text element will not shrink below the specified width unless its intrinsic width is already below that width (in which case it uses its intrinsic width as the rendered width). But it does not work unless the sum of the specified widths of all the child elements exceeds the container's width.

So I tried giving each outer elements a flex-grow parameter, so that they would grow above their specified width, if the container had room.  But I also give the outer elements a maximum width set to their intrinsic maximum content width, so they would never grow beyond the actual size of the text.  Thus I added the following styles to the wrapping `div`.

```
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 max-width: max-content;
```

With that tweak I believe it solves the entire problem.  The elements expand fully if there is room in the container.  As we add more elements the longer elements start to shrink.  But they never shrink below their specified width, so the container overflows once all inserted elements have shrunk down to that width.  But elements that started with a shorter width never flex at all.

I have added an example below.

```css
.container {
  width: 340px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 80px;
  max-width: max-content;
}

.container>div>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h5>When the items fit they expand to their intrinsic length</h5>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>Medium length</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Tiny</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Longer text element</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h5>When the container limit is reached the longer elements start shrinking</h5>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>Medium length</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Tiny</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Longer text element</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Filler</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h5>Adding more elements...</h5>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>Medium length</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Tiny</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Longer text element</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Filler</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Filler</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h5>When there is no room it overflows<br> The tiny element stays at its intrinsic width, but the bigger elements stop shrinking at the specified width</h5>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div>Medium length</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Tiny</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Longer text element</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Filler</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Filler</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Filler</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

With an extra wrapper you can do it:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container > div {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 80px;
}

.container > div > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}

.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><div>Ch 1</div></div>
  <div><div>Longer Child 2</div></div>
  <div><div>Longer Child 3</div></div>
  <div><div>Child 4</div></div>
  <div><div>Child 5</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost there! There is still one edge case which not work with that approach: I think I failed to emphasize in the fact that the children might not overflow the parent... so if I only have the first child it will be shown of 80px.  I guess I could do something with js to handle this particular case if it comes to that.

Comment: @Claudio I will try to update to cover all the cases. I thought you will always have an overflow

Answer (score 0):

**Grid Solution**

```css
.container {
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: max-content 80px 80px repeat(2,max-content);
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

You can use `javascript` to make the `grid-template-column` dynamic.
**Here is the `jquery` (javascript) solution using `flex`**

```css
.container {
            width: max-content;
            border: 1px solid black;
            display: flex;
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

```js
$(".container > div").each(function(){
    ($(this).width() < 50) ?
        $(this).css('width','max-content') :
           $(this).css('flex','0 0 80px');
})
```

This is more dynamic than the grid solution. The only thing is that you will need to have a desired number in `$(this).width() < 50` instead of fifty based on your content.