# For a CSS flexbox, allow an element to shrink to minimum(its intrinsic width, an absolute length)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a box that displays a number of text elements, one after the other along a row.  I do not want the text within each element to wrap.  Instead if there is insufficient room then it should truncate the text and show an ellipse.

This is easy to obtain using `display: flex`, and allowing each element to shrink to zero.

But the smaller elements are shrunk so much that the text almost completely disappears.  In that case I would rather shrink the smaller elements a little less, and shrink the bigger elements more.  This can also be obtained by giving each element a bigger min-width (say `100px`) so that it cannot shrink beyond a certain point.

My problem occurs when one of the text element's intrinsic width is already smaller than `100px`.  Since I just specified that the element had a longer min width, the browser leaves extra space after the element.  I don't want that extra space.

I would prefer not to use java-script.  I'm seeking a solution using CSS.  It's so close that I feel that it should be possible, but none of my attempts have come out correctly.

1. If I knew in advance which text elements were tiny, then I can specify that the tiny elements should not flex at all, and get the desired outcome.  But without using javascript I do not know which elements are tiny.
2. If I could set the min-width of an element to the minimum of its intrinsic width and 100px then I would get the desired outcome.  Although CSS does have a `min()` function which may be used for `min-width`, unfortunately it appears that I am not allowed to use `max-content` as an argument to that function.
3. The description of min-width on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width) states that `fit-content(100px)` is a syntactically valid way of specifying the min-width.  I hoped to craft an element whose minimal content size is zero, and max size is the text element's intrinsic length.  Then `fit-content(100px)` would either be 100px, or if that's larger than the intrinsic length, the intrinsic length.  But whenever I use `fit-content()` with an argument the browser says that the expression is invalid.
4. Finally I tried to use a grid display.  But then `fit-content()` either uses the intrinsic width or 100px, but does not expand further.  I tried experimenting with `minmax` with no luck (it seems I cannot put `fit-content()` as an argument to `minmax()`).  Besides I do not know the number of text elements, but a grid display wants me to specify that number so I don't think a grid can be made to work.

So is there any way to obtain the desired outcome using just CSS.  Since this text is for an Electron program, I only care about Chrome as a browser.  I have an example below showing each of my attempts.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
}

span {
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.set-min-width span {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.set-min-width .no-shrink {
  flex: none;
  min-width: initial;
}

.use-max-expression span {
  min-width: min(100px, max-content);
}

.use-fit-content div {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-width: fit-content(100px);
  display: flex;
}

.use-fit-content div span {
  min-width: 0;
}

.use-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: fit-content(100px) fit-content(100px) fit-content(100px);
}

.use-grid span {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h4>The hidden overflow allows each text item to shrink to nothing<br> Both small and medium elements are heavily truncated<br></h4>
  <section>
    <span>Medium length</span>
    <span>Tiny</span>
    <span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span>
  </section>
  <h4>By setting a min-width to 100px I can control truncation of medium element. But the tiny element now has extra space after it that I do not want.</h4>
  <section class="set-min-width">
    <span>Medium length</span>
    <span>Tiny</span>
    <span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span>
  </section>
  <h4>1: This is what I want.<br> But to obtain it I had to specify a different style for the tiny element so that it would not flex. But I don't know in advance which elements are tiny.</h4>
  <section class="set-min-width">
    <span>Medium length</span>
    <span class="no-shrink">Tiny</span>
    <span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span>
  </section>
  <h4>2: I want the min-width to be the element's max-content if this is smaller than the truncation limit<br> `min(100px, max-content)` would return the correct result, but it is not valid CSS and so is ignored</h4>
  <section class="use-max-expression">
    <span>Medium length</span>
    <span>Tiny</span>
    <span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span>
  </section>
  <h4>3: I tried to use fit-content(arg)<br> The inner element has min-width 0, so its min-content size should be 0<br> Its max-content size is the intrinsic width of the text<br> So the fit-content(100px) size should be 100px if that's smaller than intrinsic
    width, or the intrinsic width otherwise.<br> Despite MDN stating that fit-content with argument is valid CSS for min-width, the browser rejects `fit-content(100px)`</h4>
  <section class="use-fit-content">
    <div><span>Medium length</span></div>
    <div><span>Tiny</span></div>
    <div><span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span></div>
  </section>
  <h4>4: Using fit-content(100px) in a grid does not work either. The elements are indeed not expanded if natural width is smaller than 100px. But the elements do not flex to take rest of space.<br> Besides a grid won't work because the number of columns is
    not known in advance.
  </h4>
  <section class="use-grid">
    <span>Medium length</span>
    <span>Tiny</span>
    <span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64225800/8620333 probably can give you some ideas

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you.  It seems to me to be the same question.  I found your answer in it very helpful, and I was able to tweak it to solve my problem.  I have posted an answer in that other question.

Answer (score -1):

I was giving this a little play around and this was the best I could come up width. The problem that I can see is that `flex-box` is terrible for not obeying boxes without setting its inner elements with a `max-width` of some kind. There is a few other answers I found on Stackoverflow but none of them seem to really fix what you are asking for. In my answer I used `max-width` on the spans, along with `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden` to create something close to what you had requested.

code below and codepen - here https://codepen.io/rl4444/pen/oNLQVRr?editors=1100

HTML

```
<main>
  <h4>my solution</h4>
  <section class="box-items">
    <span>Medium length</span>
    <span>Tiny</span>
    <span>Longer text that has to be truncated to fit within the section.  It is far far far far too big to fit.</span>
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
main {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 300px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  
}


.box-items span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```